# Methods for breaking apart a large DbContext with many relationships

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, linqpad

A project I'm working on has DbContext that tracks a lot of different Entities. Due to the large number of relationships involved, it takes a long time to query from the context the first time around while it generates its views. In order to reduce the startup time, and better organize contexts into functional areas, I'm looking for ways to split it apart.

These are some methods I've tried so far, and problems I've seen with them:

1. Create a new smaller Context with a subset of DbSets from the huge Context.

This doesn't help, since EF seems to crawl through all the navigation properties and include all related entities anyway (according to LINQPad at least, which shows all the entities related to the Context when it's expanded in the connection panel). We have a few top-level entities that are far reaching, so there are very few subsets that can be fully isolated without removing navigation properties and doing a good amount of refactoring.

2. Split Entities into classes that include navigation properties, and ones that are just db fields, like so:

```
public class PersonLight
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int JobId { get; set; }
}

public class Person : PersonLight
{
    public Job Job { get; set; }
}

public class ContextLight : DbContext
{
    public virtual DbSet<PersonLight> People { get; set; }
}
```

No dice here as well. Even though Person isn't used at all, EF (or again, possibly just LINQPad) includes `Person` despite the fact that it can't be used. I assume this is because EF supports inheritance patterns, so it ends crawling related entities in this direction as well.

3. Do the same as #2, but with `PersonLight` and `Person` in different projects (or use `partial` classes in different projects). This is the best option so far, but it would be nice to have `PersonFields` right next to `Person` for easy reference.

So my questions are:

- Are there any better ways to do this that I'm missing?
- Why, in #3, does putting them in different projects seem to separate them enough that EF doesn't try to include both? I've tried putting them in different namespaces, but that doesn't do the trick.

Thanks.

Comment: Just how large is your data context?  I've never experienced any appreciable delays the first time (and I have around a hundred tables) and I think your trying to create "Light" versions of your entities or "partial" data contexts is not the right way to go at all.  What profiling technique have you used to determine that the size of your data context and/or entities is the culprit?

Comment: @KirkWoll Embarrassingly large...pushing 800 DbSets. Profiling always points to view generation, and we've seen decent performance gains with pregenerated views and EF updates specifically mentioning improved performance in this area. Subsequent queries are all pretty much instantaneous after the views get cached. I'm all ears for other suggestions.

Comment: LinqPad generates it's own DBContext (and does other stuff as well) and you can't stop it that I've seen. Testing this sort of stuff in LinqPad is not going to work. However, even it you split your 800 tables up into 10 contexts of 80 tables, Linq is still going to have to do all the initialisation work so overall no time will be saved. However, it may delay the init until the first time a particular context is created which would smooth things out a bit. However I don't like the idea for the reasons you state.

Comment: It does seem to have a per-context initialization process. This would only be for development time savings since the production application itself should restart/regenerate views infrequently. If someone is in a modify -> compile -> view cycle using only one smaller context it would certainly be faster. We're seeing 30-90s initialization times which can really bog down what should be quick changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Options to speed things along:

- [Generated views](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn469601.aspx)
- [Bounded Contexts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj883952.aspx)

Ironically IIS app pool only needs to generate the view once.
Command line based on my tests, generates the view each time.
Not sure what linqpad does.

BTW I didn't originally add this link since you tagged it EF6.
But in case others aren't on EF6. There are some performance improvements reported. More information here:
[EF6 Ninja edition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn532202.aspx)

Comment: We did use generated views until some EF improvements made their impact vs. loading at runtime pretty negligible. I do like segregating entities based on configuration like the second link suggests, along with some of the other ideas it presents. Thanks!